# Is there a way to make a JAX-WS client use HTTP/1.0, rather than HTTP/1.1, which appears to be the default?

Tags: jax-ws

I'm converting a web service client from axis1.4 to JAX-WS (Java 17). The Service implementation is provided by a customer, and the existing implementation is older, and may not support HTTP/1.1. I'm wondering if there's a way to change the transport of the client.  It appears that's possible in axis2 (which perhaps I should have used, instead).